Blocky edges on VBR volume (both EEVEE and Cycles)
I exported a VDB from Embergen, and imported it to Blender. On certain frames, the simulation looks blocky, both in EEEVEE and Cycles.
I tried increasing the reoslution and lowering voxel size in Embergen, and when imported into Blender, it becomes more opaque with the same material applied to it, and when I try to increase the opacity (with Blackbody Intensity), I face the same issue I faced before. It currently has about 26M voxels. Changing Step Rate and Max Steps in Cycles doesn't help. Changing Steps, Distribution and Max Depth doesn't help either.
What actually makes a difference, is limiting Custom Range End in EEVEE from 100m to 7.8. But it cuts some of the upper part of the volume.
Lowering Blackbody Intensity and Temperature also help, but they make the volume very opaque and not easily seen, and far from what I want the render to look like.
What could be the problem and how can I fix it?
Here's the render in EEVEE

Here's the material shader nodes for the volume:

